# Formatting Timestamp from Cloud Firestore to Date in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I have 2 fields: created_at and updated_at field in my DB on Cloud Firestore. They are of type Timestamp.

In my Model, I have also created the respective fields like so

```
class User {
String id;
String firstName;
String lastName;
Timestamp created_at;
Timestamp updated_at;
}
```

I have the respective fromMap and toMap functions in  my models. In my view user screen, how do I format my created_at and updated_at fields and display them in Text widgets as 8 May, 2020?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a Timestamp to a Date like so:

```
DateTime date = created_at.toDate();
```

And if you want to display it as a text you can convert your date like this:

```
String dateString = DateFormat('dd MMM, yyyy').foramt(date);
```

Therefore you need the intl Package: https://pub.dev/packages/intl

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!